# Confused about path independence

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a page from my textbook. On the previous page, I was told that 1/z over the complex plan without the origin does not have a antiderivative and therefore is not path independent. Now for this problem, the domain was redefined to be the first quadrant without the x and y axis.

1. The starting and ending points of the path itself is not even contained within the domain so how is this problem even possible?
2. If we changed the domain of 1/z so that it is in the first quadrant and include the x and y axis, and exclude the origin, would the function be path independent in this domain?

[image]